# Trigger button in an iframed JQuery UI Dialog page from Save button

Tags: jquery-ui

Here is the code I am using to initialize my dialog. I figured that since I the button doesn't exist which the page initially loads, I would need to use the on or live event to trigger the click (like in the Update call), but that hasn't worked. I confirmed that jQuery is finding the button using the console debugger but I cant for the life of me figure out how to trigger the button click.

Any suggestions?

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = $('<iframe id="pageFrame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen width="800" height="600"></iframe>');

    var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 950,
        height: 600,
        close: function () {
            iframe.attr("src", "");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                if ($("#pageFrame").contents().length > 0) {
                    if ($("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnCreateContent").length > 0) {
                        $("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnCreateContent").click()
                    }
                    else if ($fuze("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnUpdateContent").length > 0) {
                        $("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnUpdateContent").on("click", function () {
                            alert("update triggered");
                        });
                    }
                    else if ($("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnCopyContent").length > 0) {
                        $("#pageFrame").contents().find("#btnCopyContent").click();
                    }
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?\n\nUnsaved changes will be lost.")) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the answer

```
$("#pageFrame").contents()[0].getElementById("btnUpdateContent").click();
```

Hope this helps somebody else out